# UITextView.text lags when loading text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I want to display text with an UITextView, which is part of an UITabBarView and do so in the following Class:

.h - File:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DescriptionViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UITextView *descriptionText;

}
@end
```

.m - File:

```
#import "DescriptionViewController.h"
#import "Globals.h"

@interface DescriptionViewController ()


@end

@implementation DescriptionViewController



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    Globals* myGlobals = [Globals sharedGlobals];

    descriptionText.text = [myGlobals.currentLine objectAtIndex:5];

}


@end
```

When the TextView is displayed the first time it is empty, when i switch to another tab and switch back to the "TextView - Tab" it is displayed properly. But I obviously want it to be displayed correctly the first time..

I already tried to move the relevant code to the -viewDidLoad function, but nothing changed. Also, I tried the -setNeedsDisplay function without success (maybe I used it wrong? - [descriptionText setNeedsDisplay].

I appreciate any help and further code will be posted on request.

Answer (score 1):

Please set breakpoint on ViewWillAppear Method of your class then check that in first time what you are getting from NSLog("%@", [myGlobals.currentLine objectAtIndex:5]);

and you are missing [super viewWillAppear:animated];

Comment: Interesting.. It returns (null) when first called. I have no clue why something like that should happen. The string given always 'lags' somehow, like it is loaded AFTER the text is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Globals* myGlobals = [Globals sharedGlobals];

    descriptionText.text = [myGlobals.currentLine objectAtIndex:5];
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    Globals* myGlobals = [Globals sharedGlobals];

    descriptionText.text = [myGlobals.currentLine objectAtIndex:5];

}
```